# How I build XQuery for this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

hellow I want to select from my table T the XML column X 
with XQuery or by other ways? 
two values of the column X for example, in T table look like this:

#### row 1

```
<bts>
   <bt id="1">RAY</TextValue>
   <bt id="2">רוי</TextValue>
   <bt id="3">Ré</TextValue>
</bts>
```

#### row 2

```
<bts>
   <bt id="1">DAN</TextValue>
   <bt id="2">דן</TextValue>
   <bt id="3">Dé</TextValue>
</bts>
```

then I want to select all the rows from the table where the id of the element 
in the X column is @a (for example @a = 3) 
and put all the text in temp table that include them in NVARCHAR type.

```
Ré
Dé
```

if @a will be equal to 2 then the i want that the temp table will be:

```
רוי
דן
```

HOW I DO IT INT T-SQL ???

Comment: Your closing `</TextValue>` doesn't match the opening `<bt>` tag....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @WhichValue INT
SET @WhichValue = 1  -- or 2, or whatever

SELECT 
   X.value('(/bts/bt[@id=sql:variable("@WhichValue")]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM 
   dbo.T
```